# Cs50 VScode ide only running in recovery mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, cs50

Whenever I try to open the cs50 vscode workspace, it starts off by giving this notice:

> This codespace is currently running in recovery mode due to a container error. Review the creation logs, update your devcontainer configuration as needed, and run the "Rebuild Container" command to retry.

Then none of the preinstalled tools work (sqlite3, python, etc.)

Here is the last few lines to the creation log:

```
2022-04-21 01:59:29.258Z: Stop (3 ms): Run in container: cat /root/.vscode-remote/data/Machine/settings.json
2022-04-21 01:59:29.271Z: $ ls /root/.vscode-remote/bin/*/node | head -n 1
2022-04-21 01:59:29.284Z: 
2022-04-21 01:59:29.299Z: ls: cannot access '/root/.vscode-remote/bin/*/node': No such file or directory
2022-04-21 01:59:29.312Z: Stop (21 ms): Run in container: ls /root/.vscode-remote/bin/*/node | head -n 1
2022-04-21 01:59:29.330Z: userEnvProbe: none (default)
2022-04-21 01:59:29.343Z: $55.88679008Z' > '/root/.vscode-remote/data/Machine/.onCreateCommandMarker'
2022-04-21 01:59:29.358Z: 
2022-04-21 01:59:29.371Z: 
2022-04-21 01:59:29.385Z: Exit code 1
2022-04-21 01:59:29.400Z: && echo '2022-04-20T15:04:55.88679008Z' > '/root/.vscode-remote/data/Machine/.onCreateCommandMarker'
2022-04-21 01:59:29.414Z: $55.88679008Z' > '/root/.vscode-remote/data/Machine/.updateContentCommandMarker'
2022-04-21 01:59:29.428Z: 
2022-04-21 01:59:29.446Z: 
2022-04-21 01:59:29.461Z: Exit code 1
2022-04-21 01:59:29.474Z: && echo '2022-04-20T15:04:55.88679008Z' > '/root/.vscode-remote/data/Machine/.updateContentCommandMarker'
2022-04-21 01:59:29.487Z: $55.88679008Z' > '/root/.vscode-remote/data/Machine/.postCreateCommandMarker'
2022-04-21 01:59:29.503Z: Stop (455 ms): Resolving Remote
2022-04-21 01:59:29.517Z: 
2022-04-21 01:59:29.531Z: 
2022-04-21 01:59:29.545Z: Exit code 1
2022-04-21 01:59:29.578Z: && echo '2022-04-20T15:04:55.88679008Z' > '/root/.vscode-remote/data/Machine/.postCreateCommandMarker'
2022-04-21 01:59:29.610Z: $23.284538754Z' > '/root/.vscode-remote/data/Machine/.postStartCommandMarker'
2022-04-21 01:59:29.629Z: 
2022-04-21 01:59:29.643Z: 
2022-04-21 01:59:29.659Z: && echo '2022-04-21T01:59:23.284538754Z' > '/root/.vscode-remote/data/Machine/.postStartCommandMarker'
```

Here is the Pastebin for the rest of the creation log: https://pastebin.com/PnWaBv7W

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran `touch /workspaces/GITHUB_USERID/.devcontainer.json` where `GITHUB_USERID` was my own GitHub user id.

Then I clicked "Rebuild Now" to rebuild the container.

CS50 students can find theirs by visiting [www.github.com/code50](http://www.github.com/code50) .

Comment: thank you! simple, concise, useful answer +1