# My vscode workspace does not load properly: currently running in recovery mode due to a container error

Tags: visual-studio-code, cs50

Error Message : This codespace is currently running in recovery mode due to a container error. Review the creation logs, update your devcontainer configuration as needed, and run the "Rebuild Container" command to retry. Then none of the preinstalled tools work (sqlite3, python, etc.)

As advised here: [Cs50 VScode ide only running in recovery mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71948367/cs50-vscode-ide-only-running-in-recovery-mode/74223453#74223453)

I ran touch /workspaces/GITHUB_USERID/.devcontainer.json where GITHUB_USERID was my own GitHub user id.

I tried running touch /workspaces/GITHUB_USERID/.devcontainer.json where GITHUB_USERID was my own GitHub user id.

However it says "No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Try going to settings -> command palette and type Rebuild container and click "Codespaces: Rebuild container" and rebuild.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).